# Is it a good idea to use MSBuild for Visual Studio projects

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I'm new to .net and want to use a build tool for my project. I'm reading about MSBUILD and other options but recently came to know that Visual studio projects are MS Build scripts.

So, that makes me think, should I really use MSBUILD for Visual studio projects ?

Comment: This question is off topic.  Please read [help] to find out what is or isn't on topic here.

Comment: Like the answer showed, you are "forced" to use MSBuild, as the whole .NET ecosystem lives upon it. You have no other choice, and "should I really use" is not a question to be answered.

Comment: @LexLi you're not *forced* to; you could use csc etc directly; not sure why you'd ever want to, though...

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio uses MSBuild under the hood and the project system is based on it.

There are a few other tools that help with .NET builds, like [Cake](http://cakebuild.net), but for the most important part, they also call MSBuild (but help you to script it for complex scenarios).

There really isn't an alternative to MSBuild since all tools (VS, JetBrains Rider, OmniSharp (/VSCode)) require it to understand C#/VB.NET projects.

Answer (score 2):

> should I really use MSBUILD for Visual studio projects ?

Obviously, we can also use devenv.exe, csc.exe or other compilers for Visual Studio projects except MSBuild. But just as Martin`s answer, *all tools (VS, JetBrains Rider, OmniSharp (/VSCode)) require it to understand C#/VB.NET projects.* And Visual Studio hosts MSBuild to load and build managed projects. Because MSBuild is responsible for the project, almost any project in the MSBuild format can be successfully used in Visual Studio.

With MSBuild, you could build projects on a build server for .NET apps without Visual Studio.

Besides, MSBuild will give you significant flexibility in choosing what technologies you use to implement continuous integration. And custom MSBuild tasks will give you even more flexibility in implementing custom builds.

What more, If Visual Studio Team System is in your future, applications built using MSBuild will be much easier to move into that environment than those built via alternative means.

Though, we can build Visual Studio project by using other ways, **it is absolutely a good idea to use MSBuild for Visual Studio projects**.

Hope this can help you.